# Is drinking goat milk allowed in Hinduism?

Tags: dharma-shastras, manu-smriti, ayurveda

Ayurveda recommends the usage of goat's milk in its products. However, some smritis say that one should not drink goat's milk. Is drinking goat milk allowed in Hinduism?

Comment: Please do not ask for personal advice. That is against the forum rule. Please edit the question. Otherwise, the question might get closed.

Comment: If you know, please add the reference of the Smriti that prohibits goat milk.

Comment: I have read it in dharma Sindhu while author was discussing on the topic"punarupanayana

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Rickross I think the question is clear. I just want to know whether brahmachari is allowed to use Ayurvedic products with goat milk(I have Kannada version of dharma Sindhu so I won't be able to quote Sanskrit/English words of that verse). You can find dharma Sindhu condemning brahmacharis to drink goat's milk in the section of "PUNARUPANAYANA". I want to use a product called "Mahatriphala grith"(to improve my eye sight) which contain goat's milk(10ml in 100 g product). So I posted the question.

Comment: Yes I know the question is clear. You are not required to do further edits to it. @ShripadRJoshi

Comment: @Rickross Namaste do u have answer for the question. I have bought a product with goat milk for betterment of my eye sight. So please research on that and answer the question so that I get clarification.

Comment: Yes I have answered it @ShripadRJoshi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drinking milk of goat is allowed by the scriptures. Milk of deer, camel and one-hoofed animals are forbidden but not that of goat.

See the following references:

> It is forbidden to drink any type of liquor; 22 as also the milk of
> sheep, 23 camels, and deer; the milk of animals in heat or bearing
> twins; 24 and the milk of a cow during the first ten days after giving
> birth. 25
>
> **1.17.22-25 of Dharma Sutra Apasthamba**

If goat milk was forbidden then it should have been mentioned in the above but not mentioned. That implies it is allowed.

> **It is forbidden to drink the milk of a cow, a goat, or a buffalo, during the first ten days after it gives birth; 24 the milk of sheep,
> camels, and one-hoofed animals under any circumstances**; 25 the milk
> of an animal from whose udders milk flows spontaneously or of an
> animal that has borne twins, gives milk while pregnant, 26 or has lost
> her calf
>
> **Gautama Dhrama Sutras 17. 22-26**

So, the consumption of milk of goat, like cow milk, is allowed under usual circumstances. When it is not allowed is clearly mentioned in the above passage.

Similarly, we find from the Dharma Sutras of Vashishta:

> He should not drink the milk of cows in heat or whose calves have
> died, 35 or of cows, buffaloes, or goats during the first ten days
> after giving birth; 36 or water collected at the bottom of a boat.

So, the conclusion is that it is allowed to consume goat milk generally but not within ten days of the goat giving birth. But this particular restriction is not there only for goat milk its there for cow milk too. Therefore, both cow milk and goat milk are usually fit for consumption.

Comment: @Rickroos Namaste. Thank you for your answering,but I don't know meaning of one hoofed animal. Thanks for researching on my.request.

Comment: I think only horses, donkeys and zebras are one hoofed animals. Their milk is forbidden for consumption. @ShripadRJoshi

Comment: @Rockross what does hoof mean can you please explain it?I have searched in Google but I was unable to understand exact meaning.

Comment: You can see this wiki link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoof) and you can also search "one hoofed animals" on Google @ShripadRJoshi